# How to extract start and end sites based on capital letter in a sequence?

Tags: python, sequence, bioinformatics, extract

I would like to extract the start and end site information that is in capital letter. By counting the sequence length using the code below is not able to return the sequence information accurately. The P-match result that I need to process given the start site is based on the first alphabet but the start site that I actually need is the first capital letter that occur in every site. How can I retrieve the accurate start and end site? Can anyone help me?
**Text file A.txt**

```
Scanning sequence ID:   BEST1_HUMAN

          150 (-)  1.000  0.997  GGAAAggccc                                   R05891
          354 (+)  0.988  0.981  gtgtAGACAtt                                  R06227
V$CREL_01c-RelV$EVI1_05Evi-1

Scanning sequence ID:   4F2_HUMAN

          365 (+)  1.000  1.000  gggacCTACA                                   R05884
           789 (-)  1.000  1.000  gcgCGAAA                                       R05828; R05834; R05835; R05838; R05839
V$CREL_01c-RelV$E2F_02E2F
```

**Expected output:**

Sequence ID start end

```
BEST1_HUMAN 150 155
BEST1_HUMAN 358 363
4F2_HUMAN   370 370
4F2_HUMAN   792 797
```

**File B.txt**

```
Scanning sequence ID: hg17_ct_ER_ER_142

              512 (-)  0.988  0.981  taTAGCTaagc                        Evi-1          R06227
V$EVI1_05

Scanning sequence ID: hg17_ct_ER_ER_1

              213 (-)  1.000  0.989  aggggcaggGGTCA                     COUP-TF, HNF-4 R07445
V$COUP_01
```

**Expected output:**

```
hg17_ct_ER_ER_142 514 519
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1 222 227
```

**Example code:**

```
output_file = open('output.bed','w')
with open('A.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    chunks = text.split('Scanning sequence ID:')
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk:
            lines = chunk.split('\n')
            sequence_id = lines[0].strip()
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith('              '):
                    start = int(line.split()[0].strip())
                    sequence = line.split()[-2].strip()
                    stop = start + len(sequence)
                    #print sequence_id, start, stop
                    seq='%s\t%i\t%i\n' % \
                         (sequence_id,start,stop)
                    output_file.write(seq)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: So you have to capture the pattern BEST1_HUMAN and the following two numbers (150, 155). Where is the 155 in the text?

Comment: the value 155 is not provided in the P-match result. I need to process the result into a bed file which contain sequence ID, start site and end site. The result return start site that is based on first alphabet but I need the start and end site based on capital letter alphabet for example GGAAA.

Comment: I think the label and first value are best found using regexp. The second value will be calculated then.

Comment: This would probably be best done using a regexp. However, I don't understand what you want as output exectly, otherwise I would give you the exact regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will get the label and start values:

```
import re

p = "Scanning sequence ID\:\s*(?P<label>[A-Z0-9]+\_[A-Z0-9]+).*?(?P<start_value>\d+)"

with open("A.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.read()

re.findall(p,s, re.DOTALL)
```

Sample output:

```
[('BEST1_HUMAN', '150'), ('4F2_HUMAN', '365')]
```

Then there's the calculation of the second number ("end site"). In the code in the opening post I see: `sequence = line.split()[-2].strip(); stop = start + len(sequence)`. Hence I would conclude thatyou want to increment the value *start* with the string length of the second last column (GGAAAggccc etc.).

I can capture that column as well, using the following modified regexp:

```
p = "Scanning sequence ID\:\s*(?P<label>[A-Z0-9]+\_[A-Z0-9]+).*?(?P<start_value>\d+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?P<sequence>\S+)"
re.findall(p,s, re.DOTALL)
```

Sample output:

```
[('BEST1_HUMAN', '150', 'GGAAAggccc'), ('4F2_HUMAN', '365', 'gggacCTACA')]
```

Now we want to handle the situation where one label has more than one data line. For this, we need to drop `re.findall` and go to an iteration:

```
import re
with open("A.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

label_ptrn = re.compile("^Scanning sequence ID\\:\\s*(?P<label>[A-Z0-9]+\\_[A-Z0-9]+)$")
line_ptrn = re.compile("^\s+(?P<start_value>\\d+)\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+(?P<sequence>\\S+).*$")
inner_ptrn = re.compile("[A-Z]+")

all_matches = []
for line in lines:
    m = label_ptrn.match(line)
    if m:
        label = m.groupdict().get("label")
        continue
    m = line_ptrn.match(line)
    if m:
        start = m.groupdict().get("start_value")
        sequence = m.groupdict().get("sequence")
        mi = inner_ptrn.search(sequence)
        if not mi:
            continue
        span = mi.span()
        all_matches.append((label, int(start)+span[0], int(start)+span[1]))
```

Then you can print the matches as follows:

```
with open("output.bed", "w+b") as f:
    for m in all_matches:
        f.write('%s\t%i\t%i\n' % m)
```

Sample output:

```
BEST1_HUMAN 150 155
BEST1_HUMAN 358 363
4F2_HUMAN   370 375
4F2_HUMAN   792 797
```

I think the problem is solved ;)

Comment: Because the small letter is not counted. I need location from capital letter e.g. aaggTCAaagg which is TCA. If the first alphabet start with 'a' which is the value 1. Then the start location for capital letter is 5 and end with 8 because for bed file if let's say 100 sequence the location is start with 0 and end with 99. Another way to make this easier is to get the location of T and the add the value 3 for every start site.

Comment: @Xiong89 Take a look at my latest edit. I think it perfectly reproduces your example output.

Comment: However, when I input different file with different number of sequence it cannot solved it accordingly. The code I provided above can solve with different number of sequence but can't retrieve the capital letter location.

Comment: File A is just fine. When I tried with file B there is an error.

Comment: The problem is that the label in `B.txt` doesn't match the label pattern. The stand and end indices seem OK. I suggest the following change: `label_ptrn = re.compile("^Scanning sequence ID\\:\\s*(?P<label>[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)$")`